# Is it correct when the constant String is not in the pool?

Tags: java, string

I have a code in Alfresco:

```
Map properties = propertyHelper.getNodeProps(nodeRef)
QName linkedType = QName.createQNameWithValidLocalName("http://www.emc-consulting.ru/model/linked/1.0" ,"linked_type");
 Object collectionOfLinkedObjects = properties.get(linkedType);
```

It seems like Strings in linkedType QName aren't in the String's pool because they have a hashcodes different from hashcodes in properties. Why? I thought that every String placed in "" (quotas) interned to the pool by default in compile time. I can see the hashcodes in debugger. 
Everything goes well when I use the constants.
Thank you!

Comment: Why does this matter to you?

Comment: If the String has the same contents, the hashCode will be the same, no matter if it is interned or not. If the hashcodes are different, the Strings contain different characters.

Comment: Hash code of strings is based on content. If underlying characters are different, hash code is different (most likely). It does not matter how the string on which hashCode is executed came from.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me.  Perhaps you should write a minimal reproducible example that we can compile and run and see what you are talking about.

Comment: For what it is worth, the Alfresco `QName` class doesn't use an alternative `String` class.  Therefore the hashcodes for the strings in a `QName` are calculated the same as for normal strings; i.e. a hash is computed from the characters in the string, using the formula in the javadoc.  But note that the `String::hashCode` method is lazy.  If you try to look at the value in a string's private hashcode field, it will be zero unless something has already called `hashCode` on *that string instance*.